# How to add a server list into Registered Servers on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of SQL servers on the table on tbl_servers which have 500 servers.
example:

Select IP_instance, dbname, username, password from tbl_servers
which will return all SQL server and their sa credential.

--> 10.10.1.30, myDatabase, sa, password

I would like to add all of this into the Registered server, can this do by SQL scripting? or any faster way to add it?

Answer (score 1):

Phil Factor wrote a great article at the Simple-talk website that includes this and much other useful information

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-tools/registered-servers-and-central-management-server-stores/

Answer (score 0):

I think having all your SA passwords in clear in a database is really not recommanded. At least, encrypt that column in case someone get access to it.

For the automation, I use powershell to loop in the Server list and add them.

Get in the Registered server "folder":

> > set-location 'SQLSERVER:\sqlregistration\Database Engine Server Group\YourGroup'

Add the server:

> > New-Item -Name $server -ItemType Registration -Value("Server=$server; integrated security=true");

Put this in a loop "foreach" or your query result (all servers) and that should do it.

In your case, you will have to chage the "integrated security" for SA login but that should work